# How to upgrade Database First Entity Framework 4 To 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

Currently I am using EF 4 with Database first approach and now want to upgrade this to EF 6.

I have seen different sources but explains only the code approach but I want to know database first.

What is the upgrade process and please provide valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

What I have tried: I have replaced all EF 4 references with EF 6.

Comment: This is a relatively broad question. If you could explain the issues that you're having that will help people provide specific answers.

Comment: It's good that you explain what you tried, but also explain what happened when you tried. Did you get errors compiling? Running? That would help in determining what the matter is.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane, thanks for your response: I am not sure where to start this upgrade process also. it would be better to provide initial steps or any web site or process steps to do EF 6 upgrade from EF4.

Comment: Have you looked at the microsoft guid for it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Thanks for viewing my question, I tried with replacing EF 4 Dll's with EF 6 Dll's but, latest EF not showing any new features which is from EF 6 so It means its not updated. I feel my approach was not correct.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: I have seen that link now but its not mentioned for database first approach. Anyway I will try now.

Comment: Did you manually change DLLs, or change the NuGet references? The latter should be the way to go

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Did through Nuget manager

Comment: Need to create the reverse poco classes for connected databases and then use as models. To create poco classes i have used reverse poco generator.

Answer (score 1):

Need to create the reverse poco classes for connected databases and then use as models. To create poco classes i have used reverse poco generator.